# Cookie not showing up in browsers development tool application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cookies

I am working on a web app project and for which i need to authenticate the user for some protected routes so i am using jwt tokens for this need.

Technologies used in project :-

frontend --> react
backend --> node, express

Node JS backend code.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const ProductModel = require('../Schemas/productSchema')

const product = ProductModel;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    try {
        product.find(function(err, data){
            if(data){
                res.cookie("test", "test1");
                res.send(data);
            }
            else{
                res.json({message : err});
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({message : error});
    }
})
```

React frontend code.

here in this frontend code i am making a get request to the server using fetch

```js
useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData(){
            await fetch('http://localhost:5000/products')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data =>{
                // setProducts(data.data);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [])
```

In the nodejs code i am sending cookie to the browser and for good the cookie is getting shown in the chrome devtool network

But cookie is not getting shown up in the browser->devtool->application->cookies

I don't know why this happening please submit the solutions with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First, I guess that u need to import the cookie parser

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
app.use(cookieParser());
```

this lets you use the cookieParser in your application

And finally u can use it :

```
res.cookie(`...`);
```

Comment: I did it but still not working and by the way what i think cookie parser is used to break down the cookie coming from browser so i don't see any use of it in the sending of the cookie.

May be i am wrong please correct me if i am.....